# File upload failing for end-user when ASP.Net Core application published to UAT Web Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload

I have a web application built in ASP.Net Core (3.1) with a file upload feature. This has been fully tested locally and then published on our web server in UAT. I have tested it myself in UAT and it works fully, but having passed it on for user-testing, it is throwing an error when a file upload is attempted and I'm unable to determine why.

My relevant code is shown below as well as my log file with the error:

- file upload section of my homepage:

```html
            <div id="uploader" class="upload-widget">
                @(Html.DevExtreme().FileUploader()
                      .ID("file-uploader")
                      .Multiple(false)
                      .Accept("*")
                      .UploadMode(FileUploadMode.Instantly)
                      .UploadUrl(Url.Action("UploadtoServer", "Home"))
                      .OnValueChanged("fileUploader_valueChanged")
                      .OnUploaded("fileUploader_popUp"))
            </div>
```

- method on my Home controller:

```cs
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadToServer()
        {

            Log.Info("File selected for upload to server");
            var uploadsPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + _config["uploadFolder"];
            var inputPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + _config["inputFolder"];
            var files = Request.Form.Files;


            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsPath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsPath);

                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(uploadsPath, file.FileName)))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Flush();
                    }

                    Log.Info($"File {file.FileName} successfully uploaded to server");

                    MoveFromUploads(uploadsPath, file);
                    Log.Info($"File {file.FileName} copied across to Input folder");

                    var fullInputFilePath = Path.Combine(inputPath, file.FileName);
                    var loadFile = InitialiseLoadFileModel(fullInputFilePath, file);
                    UploadToDatabase(loadFile);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Error($"File upload from UI has failed: " + e);
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return new EmptyResult();

        }
```

- relevant section of my appsettings.json showing directory config:

```
  "uploadFolder": "\\wwwroot\\uploads",
  "inputFolder": "\\wwwroot\\input",
```

- and the error stack  log file after the user has attempted to process an upload:

```
2020-05-08 20:05:52,667 [32] INFO LGL.FrontEnd.Controllers.HomeController [? ?] - File selected for upload to server
2020-05-08 20:05:52,816 [32] ERROR LGL.FrontEnd.Controllers.HomeController [? ?] - File upload from UI has failed: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\zebrowsc\Desktop\DATA RISK.xlsx'.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
   at LGL.FrontEnd.Controllers.HomeController.UploadToServer() in C:\Users\barremme\source\repos\LGL\LGL.FrontEnd\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 86
2020-05-08 20:05:52,819 [32] ERROR Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware [? ?] - An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\zebrowsc\Desktop\DATA RISK.xlsx'.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
   at LGL.FrontEnd.Controllers.HomeController.UploadToServer() in C:\Users\barremme\source\repos\LGL\LGL.FrontEnd\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 86
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
2020-05-08 20:25:59,692 [36] INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime [? ?] - Application is shutting down...
```

Comment: "C:\Users\zebrowsc\Desktop\DATA RISK.xlsx" is clearly the local path from the User side. Something the Server should have no access too. And indeed something that *should* have stumbeled over the normal rights setup (special user, minimal rights) during a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C:\Users\zebrowsc\Desktop\DATA RISK.xlsx" is clearly the local path, from the Browsers side. This is not something a server can work with.

I would guess you tested on the same computer you developed on and also the same user? Of course the server could access a local file there. And during development, most of the restrictions are relaxed.

A slightly better test setup could have revealed it: As they are very vulnerable to hacking, webservers usually work under the most restrictive userirghts possible. Special user, minimal read access to programm and content directory. Under those the server should not have been able to find the file.

Ideal test would have been 2 different machines - even virtual ones - to have that extra layer between client and server.